# Create components with configuration in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a bit of experience with the Spring framework and understood the core features. However, how to create one or multiple beans from configurations dynamically at runtime? Or should you not use dependency injection at all here and just inject the dependencies normally?

Lets demonstrate this with an example. The following class represents a configuration for some class or feature in my application.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_config)
public class SomeConfig {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "some_config_id")
    private long id;

    // more properties and accessors 

}
```

Now i want to load all present configurations from my database using the `SomeConfigService`. This works fine, but what should i do now to initialize the following class with a configuration?

```
public class SomeFeature implements Runnable {

    private SomeConfig config;
    private SomeOtherService service;

    public SomeFeature(SomeConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this code here depends on some values in my config
    }
}
```

Now, we have a constructor parameter that cannot be dynamically injected by Spring.

### What i have tried so far

What i though i could do now i use one of the following options:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SomeFeature implements Runnable {

    private SomeConfig config;
    private SomeOtherService service;

    public SomeFeature(SomeConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this code here depends on some values in my config
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSomeOtherService(SomeOtherService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Here i tried to use to `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`. Construct the object first and then try to resolve all other dependencies with setter injection.

```
public class SomeFeature implements Runnable {

    private SomeConfig config;
    private SomeOtherService service;

    public SomeFeature(SomeConfig config, SomeOtherService service) {
        this.config = config;
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this code here depends on some values in my config
    }
}
```

Or i could try to remove dependency injection completely from this object and delegate construction to another object. Maybe its right to use a factory bean here that constructs these objects for me?

### What i am exactly looking for?

How can i instantiate my feature classes, such that its dependencies are resolved and is dependency injection the right choice here or not.

Comment: @Makoto I cannot see why this is a duplicate or answers my question

Comment: You started with an entity that maps Spring properties across, which led to my initial thought:  "Oh, you want to load these from a database."  So I looked around and figured that this would be an appropriate duplicate.   If this *doesn't* answer your question, **spend less time explaining the technology** and **more time explaining what you want to actually _accomplish_.**  Spring Boot has many of these problems already solved, and questioning DI at all will likely muddy your search.